# Angular digest cycle runs on which all events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In broad sense I know that AngularJS runs digest on AJAX, Mouse, Keyboard($http, ngClick, ngKeyup, ngKeydown) etc events. But there are events which requires developer to inform AngularJS to run digest explicitly.

I want to know precisely which all events are subscribed by AngularJS for auto digest cycle?

Comment: as i think any custom angular event when broadcasting or emitting not raise digest

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by runs digest with ajax, mouse, keyboard etc... If you mean $http, ngMouseDown etc... i think i would understand better.

Basically any vanilla JS event doesn't run digest. That's why $timeout and other events exists. If you run vanilla js version setTimeout digest is not called.

So i think it's pretty easy to figure out which events require you to use digest.